# combine two vectors using cbind and either or argument

Tags: r, vector, arguments, either

I have a simple question but don't know how to do it myself. I have two vectors where each contains '0' and '1' numeric values. My aim is to combine two vectors as one, and have something like this:

```
A <- c(1,1,0,0,0,1)

B <- c(0,1,1,0,0,1)
```

after combining two:

```
C <- c(1,1,1,0,0,1)
```

Basically, if either of them has 1, then it should be combined as 1, if both of them have 1, then it should be 1 too, if none of them have 1, then it should be 0.

Hope you can answer

Thank you much!
-G

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We can use `pmax` to get the output

```
pmax(A, B)
```

---

Or with `|` to coerce the binary vectors to a logical vector and then change it to binary with `+` or (`as.integer`)

```
+(A|B)
#[1] 1 1 1 0 0 1
```

Comment: @Ms.G `pmax` is 40% faster than `+()` or `as.integer`.